# How to model rules for generating geometric patterns?

Tags: image, graphics, graph, representation, fractals

For my problem it would be best to find a numeric representation of kazakh national ornaments for generating new ones. But other approaches are also fine.

The ornaments essentially consist of combinations of relatively basic ornaments. Usually the ornaments are symmetrical.

Here are few examples of basic elements:

[image] [image] [image]
[image] [image] [image]

(The images are a bit distorted)

And this is an example of a more complex ornament:

[image]

How could I encode an ornament's representation in as few numbers as possible? So that I could write a program that would generate an ornament, given some sequence of numbers

Any ideas are appreciated.

As I write this, I have thought that generating images of snowflakes may be somewhat relevant, although it's possibly just a fractal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to realize that your question is actually not how to represent them but how to generate them.

Still you might get some ideas. But don't hold your [breath](https://www.nctm.org/classroomresources/), because it can get [complicated](https://web.archive.org/web/20120610055755/http://xahlee.org/Periodic_dosage_dir/t1/cmaci_larcu3.html)

EDIT:
In researching problems such as this you could start with [L-systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system), this [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20220514204041/http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/abop/abop-ch1.pdf) seems to convey the idea.

Actually here's an attempt at an answer:
Represent it as a set of grammar rules.

Comment: Yes, but it would be best to generate them by changing values in the sequence of numbers, used in representation.

Comment: It might be, but it is obfuscating the real question if you are looking for 'the' way to generate them, if you are looking for 'a' way to generate them or just exploring your problem space then it makes sense.

Comment: In short, I was thinking of finding 'the' way similar to nine block pattern(http://www.levitated.net/daily/lev9block.html).

Comment: Given the above examples we can not say that that will be 'the' way. Nine block pattern is definitively just a way: using some set of rules it produces patterns.
Such task is relatively easy and essentially(!) different from what you are asking: the exact set of rules that will generate geometric shapes (patterns) from your problem space.

Comment: @Daniyar, you might feel this is just small semantical difference, but if you were to phrase your question as - 'how to model rules for generating a geometric patterns' you might receive much more attention and quality answers.

Comment: @Unreason, thanks for tip, I have changed the question.

Could you specify what will be the output of grammer rules? Positions and sizes of the basic ornaments?

Comment: @Daniyar, the output of grammar can be anything, take a look at the paper above it is quite interesting. That anything for a given grammar, can be for example set of rules that transform starting shapes into a certain pattern (for analogy look at an L-system that creates one type of tree branch)

Answer (score 0):

I found this dissertation (read it as book) on image texture generation. [Image Texture Tools](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/publications)